# grep + how to match word from file when word in grep is variable

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, grep

we have the following /etc/hosts file

```
130.21.25.5 kafka01.bd-dm-kag.com
130.12.22.6 kafka02.bd-dm-kag.com
130.12.22.10 kafka03.bd-dm-kag.com
```

I want to use grep in order to match the kafka01 machine , as the following

```
machine=kafka01

grep -E '(\s$machine)[[:digit:]]+'  /etc/hosts
```

but grep not matched the kafka01  ( no output from grep )

we try also

```
 grep -E '\s$machine[[:digit:]]+'  /etc/hosts
```

what is wrong with my syntax?

note - perl one linear or awk can be also considered if not solution from grep

Comment: See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: 1) You need to enclose `$machine` into double quotes, not single quotes. 2) To get a match, the name of the machine must be behind the digits in the regex, not before. 3) If you want to select the whole IP address, the regex must also foresee the presence of dots.  So use: `grep -E "[[:digit:].]+\s$machine"  /etc/hosts`.

Comment: Running a simple, without bells and whistles grep "$machine" /etc/hosts will display the line 130.21.25.5 kafka01.bd-dm-kag.com.